# Ordenando um SortedMap pelo atributo do objeto

Tags: java

Boa tarde colegas programadores de plantão. Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que cria de um formúlário através das informações contidas em um arquivo tabulato.txt. Consegui desenvolver toda a rotina de criação do formúlario, agora preciso ordená-lo, de acordo com o atributo "geopólitico"(bairros). Segue abaixo o código:

CLASSE DE CRIAÇÃO DO MAP:

```
    package classes.repository;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.SortedMap;
    import java.util.TreeMap;
    import classes.model.Clientes;
    import classes.model.Comodatos;
    import classes.model.Zonas;

            public class Tables {
        public SortedMap<String, Clientes> clientes = new TreeMap<>();
public List<Zonas> zonas = new ArrayList<>();
public Map<String, Comodatos> comodatos = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public void tables() {
    try {
        File file = new File("table.txt");
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        String leitor = bReader.readLine();
        while ((leitor = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] leitorSplit = leitor.split("\t");
            clientes.put(leitorSplit[0], new Clientes(leitorSplit)); // leitorSplit[0] == cód do cliente não pode se repetir, por isso utilizei o Map
            comodatos.put(leitorSplit[5], (new Comodatos(leitorSplit)));
        }
        File file = new File("zonasbairros.txt");
        FileReader fReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        String leitor;
        while ((leitor = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] leitorSplit = leitor.split("\t");
            zonas.add(new Zonas(leitorSplit));
        }
        bReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Implementei um comparable na classe objeto para ver se funcionava, mas não deu certo:

```
    package classes.model;
    public class Clientes implements Comparable<Clientes> {

private String cod, fantasia, razaoSocial, endereco, geopolitico, documento, codproduto, descricao, qtd;
private String[] linha;

public Clientes() {
}

public Clientes(String[] linha) {
    this.cod = linha[0];
    this.fantasia = linha[1];
    this.razaoSocial = linha[2];
    this.endereco = linha[3];
    this.geopolitico = linha[4];
}


public String getCod() {
    return cod;
}

public void setCod(String cod) {
    this.cod = cod;
}

// Getters...Setters..

@Override
public int compareTo(Clientes o) {
    return geopolitico.compareTo(o.geopolitico);
}
```

}

Conseguiria facilmente organizar com o Collections.sort se utiliza-se uma List, entretanto os dados do arquivo.txt se repetem e por isso a escolha do Map. Varias cabeças pensam melhor que uma. Alguma luz?? abraço!

Comment: O `TreeMap` do Java é baseado numa `RedBlackTree` e a chave é utilizada para comparação dos nós da arvore, o que significa que é automaticamente ordenado pelas chaves, e "impossível" de ordenar pelos valores. Uma alternativa é reconstruir a arvore reimplementando a função de comparação utilizada pela arvore para inserção, para que compare pelo valor em vez de pela chave. Ou utilizar outra estrutura de dados que não tenha esteja restrição.

Comment: Positivo Isac. Obrigado pela ajuda,. Resolvi o problema instanciando uma List<Clientes> com os dados do SortedMap<Clientes>. Desta forma consegui tratar a ordenação das informações sem problema.